Can a linear combination of $\operatorname{ReLU}$ functions have compact support?
Let $\operatorname{ReLU}:\mathbb{R}^1 \to \mathbb{R}^1$ be defined by $\operatorname{ReLU}(t) = \max(0,t)$.
Consider functions $f:\mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}$ of the form
$$
f(x) = b_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i\operatorname{ReLU}(w_i^\top x + b_i)
$$
where $w_i \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and $b_i \in \mathbb{R}$.
Is it possible to find any non-zero such $f$ with compact support and nonzero integral?
If so this would be useful for a constructive version of an "unbounded width" Universal Approximation Theorem for neural networks.  We could use such an $f$ to build an approximate identity for convolution.
It is possible when $p=1$ by explicit construction as shown by
$$x \mapsto \operatorname{ReLU}(x+1)+\operatorname{ReLU}(x-1) -2 \operatorname{ReLU}(x)$$
I suspect the answer is negative when $p \geq 2$ (probably for trivial reasons), but I wasn't able to find a proof.

This is true (i.e., this is impossible in higher dimensions), but the proof is not quite straightforward.
See Theorem 6.1 and it's proof in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.03812

Excellent!  As a followup question:  I imagine that it is possible given a certain number of layers dependent on $p$.  Are you aware of a construction?  If so, are there any constructions with a minimum number of layers?  This would give a constructive universal approximation theorem with bounded width.

Hmm, I think $\operatorname{ReLU}(1 - \displaystyle \sum_{w \in {-1,1}^p}\operatorname{ReLU}(w^\top x)) )$ does the trick, which gives us an arbitrary width universal approximation theorem for depth 2.

I attract your attention on the fact that cardinal spline functions are typical examples of what you are looking for. See my recent answer here where $(...)_+$ is the equivalent of your ReLU function.

The example you give at the end is a particular case of cardinal spline with $>0$ integral.
